# Best way to share code other than MS Word

Tags: python, jenkins, deployment, ms-word, ms-office

I have a deployment process for a Jenkins server which includes running some bash commands like below

```
sudo yum install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install mysql-connector-python
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key
sudo yum install Jenkins
sudo amazon-linux-extras install java-openjdk11
```

I am currently working on MS Word and will share the same to another person who wants to deploy jenkins but this word document is not the most ideal way to share this document.

So my question is, Is there a better way to create documentations?, which have some step, maybe some images and code snippets. Keep in mind the solution should have enterprise level support or should be free for all.

Comment: Also this method should be offline. So like create a file and then share it and the user can open the file.

Comment: Create a bash script with the code, create a  README.md with the instructions. Put theses files in github, bitbucket, gitlab... Send the link to the repo to others.